# Nested Menu options does not respond when clicked

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I have a dilemma with my telegram bot. I was trying to prompt a response from my nested menu selection upon clicking it. However, it prompts an error saying: **"Message is not modified: specified new message content and reply markup are exactly the same as a current content and reply markup of the message"**

Is there something I missed out when triggering the respond? Still new to this, so pardon the novice question

```
def start(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text(main_menu_message(),
                              reply_markup=main_menu_keyboard())


def main_menu(update,context):
    query = update.callback_query
    context.bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=query.message.chat_id,
                                  message_id=query.message.message_id,
                                  text=main_menu_message(),
                                  reply_markup=main_menu_keyboard())


def first_menu(update, context):
    query = update.callback_query
    # print(context.match)
    context.bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=query.message.chat_id,
                                  message_id=query.message.message_id,
                                  text=first_menu_message(),
                                  reply_markup=first_menu_keyboard())



# and so on for every callback_data option
def first_submenu(update):
    update.message.reply_text("Use /start to test this bot.")


################ Keyboard #######################
def main_menu_keyboard():
    keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton("Exercise", callback_data='m1'),
                 InlineKeyboardButton("Option 2", callback_data='m2')],
                [InlineKeyboardButton("Option 3", callback_data='m3')]]
    return InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)


def first_menu_keyboard():
    keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton('Running', callback_data='m1_1')],
              [InlineKeyboardButton('Push Ups', callback_data='m1_2')],
              [InlineKeyboardButton('Back', callback_data='main')]]
    return InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)


####### Messages ############
def main_menu_message():
    return 'Choose the option:'


def first_menu_message():
    return 'Select exercise:'


def main():
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(main_menu, pattern='main'))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(first_menu, pattern='m1'))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(first_submenu, pattern='m1_1'))


    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    updater = Updater(TOKEN, use_context=True)
    main()
```

My current stacktrace states:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\dispatcher.py", line 390, in process_update
    handler.handle_update(update, self, check, context)
  File "Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\handler.py", line 117, in handle_update
    return self.callback(update, context)
  File "PycharmProjects/project/app.py", line 32, in first_menu
    reply_markup=first_menu_keyboard())
  File "<decorator-gen-27>", line 2, in edit_message_text
  File "Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\telegram\bot.py", line 67, in decorator
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\telegram\bot.py", line 1834, in edit_message_text
    return self._message(url, data, timeout=timeout, reply_markup=reply_markup, **kwargs)
  File "Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\telegram\bot.py", line 172, in _message
    result = self._request.post(url, data, timeout=timeout)
  File "Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\telegram\utils\request.py", line 334, in post
    **urlopen_kwargs)
  File "Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\telegram\utils\request.py", line 245, in _request_wrapper
    raise BadRequest(message)
telegram.error.BadRequest: Message is not modified: specified new message content and reply markup are exactly the same as a current content and reply markup of the message'
```

Comment: Can you add your complete Stacktrace so we can see where your Error occurs?

Comment: @Justlearnedit Sorry for the late reply! I have just added my stacktrace to my post

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the Telegram Api isn't yet ready for this. They also wrote about it in [the docs.](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#updating-messages)

> Please note, that it is currently only possible to edit messages without reply_markup or with inline keyboards.

Comment: Oh so sorry, I uploaded the code mistakenly as I was trying out 2 methods to see if my bot will respond to either.

The one I was trying to get a response currently is `update.message.reply_text("Use /start to test this bot.")`